# How to anti-alias layers against their superviews in iOS?

Tags: iphone, uiview, ios4

I'm trying to lay out a bunch of views as shown in this photo:

[image: screenshot]

Each view has sublayers whose backgroundColor produces the colours you see.
The problem is that when the view is rotated, the sublayer doesn't anti-alias, so these ugly white specks appear (I confirmed that they are indeed the backgroundColor of the UIView)

Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: How many layers do you have??

Comment: there are about 90 UIViews each with 6-7 layers. The layers aren't touching each other though